# mac osx css desktop background

Tags: css, macos, background, desktop

Is it possible to use pure CSS instead of an image as the desktop background?

simplfied example

    `body {
      background: #000;
    }`

result: desktop background goes black

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible: first of all that CSS code should be interpreted by the OS itself, like a browser which I don't think it happens. The CSS code is parsed and interpreted by the browser. If you want black background using an automation script (i think that was the ideea behind your question) i suggest to create a script that can manipulate OS settings (e.g.: no background picture, solid color black). I'm not very good at OSX programming, but it may be some API's that you can use.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use black background (#000) go to:

System Preferences  > Desktop & Screen Saver > (Under Apple Choose) Solid Colors > (The Click) Custom Color...

and there you can pick any solid color

as for using css inside html file i know it was perfectly possible on Microsoft Windows (i tried it i few years ago to put an html file as background and put the css inside it) but in Mac i've never seen any option to do that,

but it is possible with third party programs

Try Web Desktop i don't know if it works as it is very old

[WebDesktop](http://code.google.com/p/webdesktop-macosx/)

you can also refer to this page to find your answer

[Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/160949/how-do-i-set-my-wallpaper-to-a-web-page-on-mac-os-x)

Comment: thanks for your answer. i know that i can change the background color of the desktop directly. my example above is a very simplified one. i will try WebDesktop and the [Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/160949/how-do-i-set-my-wallpaper-to-a-web-page-on-mac-os-x) tips